# How to edit subscription in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

How do I edit a subscription in Azure API Management. From the Azure Portal I do not see any edit option when to edit a subscription.

[image]

Comment: check this https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/billing/billing-how-to-change-azure-account-profile

Comment: not I am not talking about azure subscription I am talking about the subscription feature inside Azure API Management

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible from portal at the moment. The only way is either through API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/subscription/update) or resource explorer (https://resources.azure.com/).

Comment: how about powershell? Is there any powershell AZ command that can do the same?

Comment: There is powershell SDK, but no az support for now.